# Embed Power Pages in external webpages as iframe

Tags: web, power-platform

How can I enable embedding of power pages in external website with iframe?

I have set HTTP/X-Frame-Options to "SAMEORIGIN". Is it okay? Which site settings should I complete to enable iframe. Schould I try something with CSP?